# NHibernate Session/Transacion management with StructureMap Nested Containers in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, structuremap

I would like to ask to share your experience on NHibernate Session and Transaction management with StructureMap Nested Containers in ASP.NET MVC Application. Have anyone tried to create an `ActionFilterAttribute` that will be parametrized with transaction isolation level and override `OnActionExecuting`, `OnActionExecuted`, `OnResultExecuted` to begin and commit\rollback NHibernate transaction. I would really appreciate your expertise.

I used [Building a Better MVC Dependency Resolver](http://www.mikeobrien.net/blog/building-better-mvc-dependency-resolver/) to build DependencyResolver, and for injecting ISession to TransactionAttribute [Dependency Injection in ASP.NET MVC: Filters](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/05/03/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-filters/).

Also, I create TransactionAttribute class with the following implementation:

```
public class TransactionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public ISession Session { get; set; }
    public bool Distributed { get; set; }

    public IsolationLevel IsolationLevel
    {
        get { return _isolationLevel; }
        set { _isolationLevel = value; }
    }

    private ITransaction _sessionTransaction;
    private TransactionScope _transactionScope;
    private IsolationLevel _isolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
            return;

        if (Session.Transaction == null || !Session.Transaction.IsActive)
        {
            if (Distributed)
                _transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required);

            _sessionTransaction = Session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel);
        }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
            return;

        if (_sessionTransaction != null)
        {
            if (filterContext.Exception != null && !filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
            {
                try
                {
                    _sessionTransaction.Rollback();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (_transactionScope != null)
                        _transactionScope.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
            return;

        if (_sessionTransaction != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (filterContext.Exception == null || filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
                {
                    _sessionTransaction.Commit();

                    if (_transactionScope != null)
                        _transactionScope.Complete();
                }
                else
                {
                    _sessionTransaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (_transactionScope != null)
                    _transactionScope.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use convention to make sure we create unqiue instance for controllers:

```
public class ControllerConvention : IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        if (type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract && typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            registry.For(type).LifecycleIs(InstanceScope.Unique).Add(type);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that it works in simple cases. However, sometimes in more complicated cases I receive error messages regarding access to already disposed objects. Also, I added logging and noticed that TransactionAttribute object instances are often reused, because Session property is already assigned with an old object.

I would like also to know if it is possible to control lifecycle of ActionFilterAttributes in ASP.NET MVC Application to be able to dispose it through Nested Container together with NHibernate Session. Should ActionFilterAttribute be completely stateless and what would be good implementation for it.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: What problems are you having? What have you tried?

Comment: How are you setting the Session property in your attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are having this problem because ActionFilters are not transient. You reuse the same instance of it through out the app.

You can manage your session by adding a property to your nhibernate config:

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">web</property>
```

Then you can bind the session in your attribute like this:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
    session.BeginTransaction();
}
```

then to release it you can do:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    var session = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
    var transaction = session.Transaction;
    if (transaction != null && transaction.IsActive)
    {
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory);
    session.Close();
}
```

There is a great post on this here: http://www.piotrwalat.net/nhibernate-session-management-in-asp-net-web-api/

It applies to MVC just as much as it does to WebAPI